# How to start wiremock server from a spring boot application on the same port?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wiremock

As per my requirement, I need to integrate wiremock server from a spring boot application on the same port. 
I have successfully run the server and spring boot application but on a different port.
But when I am trying to run them on same port, it throws an exception mentioned below:
**Can someone help me in resolving this issue?**

---

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321) ~[wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80) ~[wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236) ~[wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366) [wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServer.start(JettyHttpServer.java:130) [wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:143) [wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.fil.dc.service.virtualization.controller.ServiceVirtualizationController.runMapping(ServiceVirtualizationController.java:295) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206) [websocket-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481) [jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110) [jetty-io-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672) ~[jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590) ~[jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

2017-06-29 11:41:38.083  WARN 4868 --- [qtp718130408-20] w.o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle    : FAILED wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@28ca7e2f: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Comment: Don't run them at the same time on the same port.

Comment: Have you looked into this yet: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/1.0.x/samples/wiremock-native I wanted to have my wiremock on spring boot but never got a chance to work on it. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to do this is to have spring-boot and wiremock started on different ports. Use proxy server like nginx started on the desired port and configure redirection rules to your spring-boot app and wiremock.

Answer (score 0):

In my local below solution in working
Use different ports both

```
@Bean
    public void wireMockOptions() throws IOException
    {
        int port =8088;
        WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(port); //No-args constructor will start on port 8080, no HTTPS
        wireMockServer.start();
        WireMock.configureFor("localhost", port);
        wireMockServer.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/baeldung")).willReturn(WireMock.aResponse().withBody("Welcome to Baeldung!")));
    }
```